# Excel ActiveX Combo Box not Showing Selection

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I'm using a ActiveX Combo Box to show all or some Worksheets. In addition to that, on the same worksheet I have some Form Controls Check Boxes where the user can use them as filters for the Combo Box. So for instance, each check box have the name of department and so when one is checked the list will be updated with the worksheets related to that name. Which works fine.

However, the problem I have is that if I do choose an option from the Combo Box drop down list, it doesn't come up on the field of the Combo Box.

Here is the code I'm using at the moment.

```
Private Sub TransferList_DropButtonClick()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    I = 1
    TransferList.Clear
    For Each ws In Sheets
        If ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox_Viva").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
            TransferList.AddItem ws.Name
            I = I + 1
        End If
    Next ws
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I did some research and I did find that by using the `TransferList_Change` the issue is resolved but the filtering is not working (no change whether a check box is `True` or `False`).

What am I missing?

Cheers.

Comment: Btw, I just started writing the code for the "filtering" so, that is just a first attempt for me to see how it's working. The reason I used 'TransferList_DropButtonClick' is because the number of worksheets changes as well as their names. If you have any alternative, smarter way pls feel free to share.

Comment: Please, try using the check boxes assigned macro to load the combo. The combo events should be used for something else...

Comment: Hey FaneDuru, not sure what am I suppose to do. I'm not experienced in coding... Could you pls be more explicit?

Comment: So, You should assign a macro (or more) to the check boxes based on which value the combo should be loaded/filtered. And the combo should be loaded **when such a check box will be changed**. Now you said that the check boxes are **on the same sheet** and I suppose that you do not have all of them named identic. You should move the code you placed in the combo event, in that sub. And taking care to use all check boxes I (only) suppose that have to be taken in consideration for a specific loading. You can know what combo was clicked using `Application.Caller`, if assign the same `Sub` to all...

Comment: If I should know what you want accomplishing (from the words part...) I can help with a piece of code, too. But I must confess I do not know what you try doing...

Comment: Since you do not explain anything regarding what you want accomplishing, we are not mind readers. Your code does not make the question clearer, too. I will try to cultivate my imagination. So, you have on a sheet so many check boxes as many sheets exist in that specific workbook. Is this assumption correct? If yes, I suppose that they are named exactly as each workbook sheet. Is that assumption correct, too? Independent of your answer, **do you want loading the combo with only the sheets having their corresponding check boxes checked/ticked**? If my scenario is wrong, try explaining yours...

Comment: Forget about my time... Does my imagined scenario match yours? At least a part? If not completed, please focusing on clearly describing what you need, in the way I tried doing it.

Comment: So, I have a workbook with multiple sheets. Now the number of sheets increasing or decreasing every day. The sheets named like so ‘mmyy”Department name””product name”’. The dep and product names are shortened but are unique across products and departments. So, what I’m trying to do is to have a combo box list which will lists all the sheets so people can navigate from there. According to the check boxes, the list in the combo box can be reduced to selected department(s) and/or products. That way people can find the worksheet they want easier. Hope that makes sens

Comment: You started explaining but your way is still not clear. Based on **what logic** the code should 'understand' the relation between the check box names and the sheets to be loaded in combo? Give some examples, please. Something like: A check box named "Mydepartent1" should load sheets named "0921 Mydepartent1 myProduct", "1021 My departent1 myProduct" and "0921 My departent1 myProduct13". Something like that. **You have to define a rule based on what the code to correlate somehow the check boxes name with the sheets name**. And tell us, of course...

Comment: So, each check box (either department or product) is named as ‘CheckBox&(Product or Department)’. From then I would remove the “CheckBox” and I would keep only the first 3 letters of the product/department from the ‘True’ checkbox. So, in the loop to get all the sheet I would use if to ‘add item’ if the ‘sheet.name’ contain the 3 letters of product and or Department.

Comment: I do not understand something useful in order to make a piece of code. I clearly told you **to give us examples**. If you would not have anything there, I could suggest you a logical way, but if you have already these controls already named, **I need to understand the correlation**. From the way you explaining, I am afraid I cannot understand, if you do not make 2 - 3 examples, as I did above...

Comment: How this way of naming (‘mmyy”Department name””product name”’) should be understood? Are there double quotes in the name? I have some doubts. Aren't the department name and product name not separated at all? If yes, how to know where from the product name starts? If separated, why do not show you **exactly** some such names and with which check box(es) name to be matched...? I must leave the office in about 40 minutes and I started loosing my enthusiasm, no offence. I tried clearly explaining what is to be delivered to be helped, but you still try explaining in your way, which is not clear...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237124/discussion-between-geo-koro-and-faneduru).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment I will leave in some minutes. Please, try understanding the next way of working and extrapolate it at your situation. If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask. But I will be able to answer only after some hours, when I will  be at home.

1. Open a new workbook and save it as 'xlxm`, to accept macros.
2. Place on the working sheet a combo box (ActiveX type) and so many Form Type check boxes as workbook number of sheets. Name them (name and caption) exactly as the sheets, or in a way to make them matching one or some more sheets. Name the combo as "TransferList".
3. Copy the next code in a Standard module:

```
Sub LoadSheets_Combo()
     Dim ws As Worksheet, cmb As MSForms.ComboBox
     Set cmb = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TransferList").Object
     cmb.Clear
     For Each ws In Sheets
            If ActiveSheet.Shapes(ws.Name).ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
                cmb.AddItem ws.Name
            End If
     Next
End Sub
```

4. Right click on each check box and choose `Assign macro...` and choose 'Maros in: This workbook`and at 'Macro name' choose`LoadSheets_Combo`.
5. Start paying with check box values and see how the combo is loaded, only with the sheets matching (somehow) with the **ticked** check boxes.

Test the above suggested scenario and send some feedback...

**Edited**:

Please, try the next code able to do what (I understood) you need for your case:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoadSheets_Combo()
     Dim ws As Worksheet, cmb As MSForms.ComboBox, strDep As String, strProd As String, arrDep, arrProd
     Dim chB As CheckBox, iD As Long, iP As Long, mtch, arrL(), boolAllFalse As Boolean
     
     'ReDim the arrays keeping departments and products at their maximum possible size:
     ReDim arrDep(ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count - 1): ReDim arrProd(ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count - 1):
     For Each chB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes  'iterate between check boxes:
        If Mid(chB.Name, 9, 2) = "De" Then     'if a check box refers a department name:
            If chB.Value = 1 Then                   'if its value is True:
                arrDep(iD) = chB.Name: iD = iD + 1 'put it in the departments array
            End If
        End If
        If Mid(chB.Name, 9, 2) = "Pr" Then    'if a check box refers a product name:
            If chB.Value = 1 Then                 'if its value is True:
                arrProd(iP) = chB.Name: iP = iP + 1 'put it in the products array
            End If
        End If
     Next
     If iD > 0 Then ReDim Preserve arrDep(iD - 1) 'redim the array preserving only the loaded elements
     If iP > 0 Then ReDim Preserve arrProd(iP - 1) 'redim the array preserving only the loaded elements
     Set cmb = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TransferList").Object 'set the combo to be loaded
     cmb.Clear                                                'clear the combo items
     boolAllFalse = onlyFalseChkB   'check if all check boxes value is False and place the result in a boolean var
     For Each ws In Sheets                              'iterate between all sehets
        If boolAllFalse Then                              'if all checkboxes value are False:
            cmb.AddItem ws.Name                      'add the sheet name in the combo
        Else                                                   'if not all check boxes value are False:
            If iD > 0 Then                                 'if there are department check boxes in departments array:
               mtch = Application.Match("CheckBox" & Mid(ws.Name, 9, 3), arrDep, 0) 'check if the sheet is found in the array
               If Not IsError(mtch) Then               'if found
                   If cmb.ListCount > 0 Then          'if there are items in the combo
                       arrL = cmb.List                     'extract the combo items in an array a 2D array with 10 columns (fastest way)
                       ReDim Preserve arrL(0 To cmb.ListCount - 1, 0 To 0) 'replace all (Null) values from columns 1 to 10)
                       mtch = Application.Match(ws.Name, arrL, 0)             'check if the sheet name is already added in the combo
                       If IsError(mtch) Then            'if not added:
                           cmb.AddItem ws.Name      'add it
                       End If
                   Else
                       cmb.AddItem ws.Name          'add the sheet name in the combo, if combo does not have any item (yet)
                   End If
               End If
           End If
           'check products chkB:
            If iP > 0 Then                               'proceed in the same way for the products check boxes array:
               mtch = Application.Match("CheckBox" & Right(ws.Name, 3), arrProd, 0)
               If Not IsError(mtch) Then
                   If cmb.ListCount > 0 Then
                       arrL = cmb.List
                       ReDim Preserve arrL(0 To cmb.ListCount - 1, 0 To 0)
                       mtch = Application.Match(ws.Name, arrL, 0)
                       If IsError(mtch) Then
                           cmb.AddItem ws.Name
                       End If
                   Else
                       cmb.AddItem ws.Name
                   End If
               End If
           End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Function onlyFalseChkB() As Boolean
    Dim chB As CheckBox
    For Each chB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If chB.Value = 1 Then Exit Function
    Next
    onlyFalseChkB = True
End Function
```

In order to load the combo according to the above `Sub` rules **when the sheet is activated**, please copy the next code event in the sheet keeping the controls code module:

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    LoadSheets_Combo
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Haven’t had the chance to check it as yet. I’ll get back to you later

Comment: I'm getting a runtime error '-2147467259 (80004005)' on 'cmb.Clear'

Comment: @Geo Koro Are there in the active sheet any ActiveX combo box named "TransferList"? I created a test workbook and it works as it should. Please, download it from [here](https://easyupload.io/z3dhda) and see it working. Just play with the three check boxes value and check what is loaded in the combo...

Comment: Thank you sooooo much for your time. Is working! Not sure what I did wrong before but I started a new workbook and it does work. Now I need to work how I'm going to apply multiple filters.

Comment: Please, test the new workbook downloading it from [here](https://easyupload.io/n9n4zi) and send some feedback. I downloaded the previous one on somebody else laptop and transformed it according to my understanding. Please, confirm that my understanding was correct...

Comment: That is amazing FaneDuru!!!!! Excactly what I planned to do. Tbh it looks "a bit" more complicated than I thought. It does "filtering" the worksheet list to be added on the combo box perfectly and very quick. Still trying to understand the code... Thank so much, you've done a lot of work! One think I wanted to ask (which I didn't think about) is how the combo box will list all the worksheets when all the checkboxes are False?

Comment: @Geo Koro OK. A new function to initially determine if all check boxes are false should be created. Then, the sub called by any check box change to also be called by the sheet activate event. In this way, the combo is loaded according to the rules when initially the sheet is activated. I will post the updated code, also commenting the code lines which cannot be easily understood, if not experienced...

Comment: @Geo Koro Please, check the updated answer. And download the updated workbook from [here](https://easyupload.io/sskhwg).

Comment: It is amazing you added the comments to help me understand the steps. Especially since I am not familiar with few thing you are using in the module. The combo is not loaded if I initially click it (for instance once I open the file or if I create a copy the sheet) but only once I tick/untick a box. Shouldn't be `worskheet_activate`?

Comment: Of course, Activate... I wrote about this intention. I did not test this part being concinced I used Activate and it should work. :)

Comment: you've done great work and I really appreciate your help and time! It works like a charm, despite if I add more/less departments/products! Thank you soooo much again!

Comment: Hey FaneDuru, I have a question. So far everything works perfect for me with what you've done. I have also you code to extract data from specific dep and/or products. Before you helped me with your code, I had never used arrays (or collections/dictionaries) so I have no prior experience. Once the workbook contain many sheets, would the process of "filterring" slow down (mean looping through sheets and creating array)? Can the array be fixed until a next sheet is added? For instance, I have 20 sheets in the array today. Next sheet will be just added to previous 20 instead of looping all sheets

Comment: As I said, I have no experience with arrays but I was just wondering how thing will work when sheet number is significant big.

Comment: @Geo Koro Not so clear (for me, at least...) what you want accomplishing. Are you speaking about a Sheets array, or about the sheets content arrays? What does "20 sheets in the array" means? In principle, an array stays in the memory on all duration of the code running, except the case when you erase it. It can be also used, even after code running, if it is declared on top of the module `As Private`, from the same module, or `As Public` from all existing modules... I think, it would be good to place a question clearly describing what you intend to do and tag me here (with question link).

Comment: I just asked the question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69298182/excel-vba-array-basic-understanding). Please feel free to add/clarify things.