# Excel VBA Array - Basic Understanding

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Everyone,

I just need some clarification regarding array for my understanding. I have minimum experience in coding but I've never used arrays (collections or dictionaries) before.

I will explain briefly what I have on a project, which hopefully will help you understand my question. I have a workbook where I store data for each day for three departments and 6 products. Every worksheet is named after the date (ddmmyy), department and product (i.e. 230921De1Pr1), which unique. In the past, I had a dynamic named range (I was using [that](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/07/19/excel-dynamic-named-range/) method) where the worksheet name was added everytime the a worksheet was created. Then, I had a combobox in each sheet which listed all the worksheets using that named range, from where the users could "navigate" to other worksheets using hyperlinks. However, after the number of worksheets was getting bigger the list was not easy to read.

This year, I thought I will add some "filters" (using checkboxes) where people can narrow down the list. For instance, if user "check" the Department 1 checkbox the list will contain only the selected department. I wasn't sure how to do that so I asked for help here. After spending some time to explain myself, @FaneDuru put [everything together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69176062/excel-activex-combo-box-not-showing-selection) for me, which works perfectly. The code creates an array with all the worksheets after looping through them (which is then used to add the sheets into the combobox filtered).

At the moment (I have only 20-30 sheets) everything works instantly. I still trying to understand the code provided to me so, the following question might not be relevant. Anyway, my question is the following: Once the number of worksheets gets really big, will the process of creating the array by looping through the worksheets slow down (iterating through hundreds of worksheets)? If that's the case, can the array be created once and then each new worksheet is added on the array once is created (instead of the array is recreated each time)?

Edit - After seeing some comments below, I realized that I forgot to say that the workbook is saved on SharePoint and is used by 8-10 different users.

Comment: You could count the checkboxes by type and then allocate each array once. The arrays exist anyway in each worksheet.

Comment: There is no easy way in preserving an array between Excel sessions (you would need to write it to a file or perhaps store it in a hidden worksheet) though it is possible to preserve it between runs of a sub while a workbook is open. In any event, why not cross that bridge if you come to it? Performance will eventually degrade, but without careful timing data you can't really predict how many worksheets would lead to a noticeable problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's a good idea about writing the array in the a worksheet if the performance drop significantly.